# How to use PowerShell to schedule sourcing an R script?

Tags: r, powershell

My goal is to use PowerShell to schedule the sourcing of an R script.

My current work flow is that I open RStudio, click the "Source" button in the upper right corner. Then I wait until it's finished, and close RStudio. I change nothing in the R script.

In PowerShell I've been using its Register-ScheduledJob cmdlet to kick off C# programs on a daily schedule. And here's the problem, I can't find an example of effectively using PowerShell to source an R script.

I believe the PowerShell script should probably use the Invoke-Expression cmdlet. But I'm not 100% sure.

To no avail I've tried this: 
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4revised\bin\x64\Rterm.exe" -RedirectStandardInput "C:\MyScript.R"

Also, I'd like to avoid the solution that uses CMD BATCH as that's defeating the purpose of using PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If just sourcing the R script is what you're looking for then one way to do is something like this

```
& "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/tests/demos.R"
```

where "*C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\Rscript.exe*" is path Rscript in your local R installation and "*C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/tests/demos.R*" is path to script you'd normally **source()** directly in RStudio.
One thing to keep in mind is depending on location of files your R script needs you might need to adjust your script with appropriate **setwd()**

Comment: PowerShell refers to Microsoft PowerShell. It's the .NET framework's shell scripting language. It's not got an "&" operator so I'm assuming you mistook my question.

Comment: My understanding was you'd like to run .R scripts from PowerShell. I'm referring to '&' as PowerShell call command - so if you use line from my example in PowerShell script, you will be able to execute the .R script this way, pipe the output to another cmdlet if needed to or pickup data results or plots .R script generated and further work with them in PowerShell. Maybe you have some additional constraints/requirements for solution you need?

Comment: Thanks Martin. I did not know it was possible to do this.